# Obtener datos de tablas de diferente base de datos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un dilema que trato de hacer algo que no se si es posible siquiera, tengo 2 bases de datos `dpnmwin` y `spi_intranet` de las cuales `dpnmwin` es una ya existente de hace tiempo y la cual no puedo tocar su estructura para nada por lo cual tuve que crear la otra. En `dpnmwin` se encuentran muchos datos de empleados los cuales traigo sin problema en una consulta entre las 2 base de datos, el problema viene cuando trato de obtener el nombre del `rol` que obtienen los empleados en el sistema que desarrollo. `spi_intranet` la tuve que crear porque la otra base de datos no tenia tablas o campos para informacion importante que necesito como (roles, usuario, password), por eso cree la otra.

Con esta consulta:

```
$user = Employee::join('spi_intranet.users', 'dpnmwin.nmtrabajador.CODIGO', 'spi_intranet.users.ci')
                            ->where('dpnmwin.nmtrabajador.CODIGO', '=', $auth->ci)
                            ->first();
```

Me trae todos los datos sin problema pero el `rol` del usuario me trae es el `id` del `rol` que poseen en tabla `roles` que se encuentra en `spi_intranet`, con relaciones en laravel puedo sacar el `name` del rol pero solo del usuario que en ese momento este logeado, pero de todos los demas solo me trae el `id`. Trate de hacer una relacion entre la tabla `nmtrabajador (dpnmwin)` y `roles (spi_intranet)` asi

Model Employee

```
public function role(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

Model Role

```
public function employee(){

   return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');

}
```

De lo cual me arroja el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'dpnmwin.roles' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `roles` where
>   `roles`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

Y se que el error es porque en la tabla `nmtrabajador` no existe un campo `roles`

PREGUNTA: ¿Es posible hacer esta relacion entre 2 tablas de diferentes tablas? o ¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Es posible hacer esta relacion entre 2 tablas de diferentes tablas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que te funcionen bien las relaciones entre 2 bases de datos tenés que especificar la conexión en cada modelo.

No entiendo bien como están compuestas tus bases de datos o tus conexiones, pero suponiendo que:
***config/database***

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
]
```

***.env***

```
DB_DATABASE=dpnmwin  

DB_DATABASE_2=spi_intranet
```

En tu caso sería algo como:

***Model Employee***

```
protected $connection = 'mysql'; // mysql -> dpnmwin
protected $table = 'nmtrabajador'; // supongo que se llama aí por la consulta que pusiste en la presunta

public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'role_id'); 
    // Estoy suponiendo que el id del rol lo almacenás 
    // en el campo role_id pero si se llama de otra manera 
    // debes modificar eso
}
```

***Model Role***

```
protected $connection = 'mysql2'; // mysql2 -> spi_intranet
protected $table = 'roles';

public function employee() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');    
}
```

Con esto deberías de poder hacer

```
$employee_rol = Employee::find(1)->role; // Rol del usuario con id 1
$rol_employee = Rol::find(1)->employee; // Usuarios con el id de rol 1
dd($employee_rol, $rol_employee);
```

Mas data en la [Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)